# Do the light that we see from stars/galaxies travel at the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction

From my understanding, the speed of light is reduced when traveling in a medium. Also, space is the closest thing we have to a vacuum, but it is not a perfect vacuum.

So I wonder if the almost vacuum effect of space is meaningful enough to be taken into account when calculating the location of galaxies & stars billions of light-years away from us?

Comment: I believe that the density is so low that the refractive index is taken as one, but could not find by google any  calculations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is light actually faster than what our present measurements tell us?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/426912/)

Comment: Yes you are right!! Space is the closest we have to a vacuum. It has 30 particles/$m^3$ and some voids in space have 4-5 particles/$m^3$. But according to me that does not effect the speed of light that much as these particles are too small to increase the **optical** density of space.

Comment: Found this https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2000/DaWeiCai.shtmlvfor density in outer space.